# How do apps retrieve my saved wifi information on android devices?

Tags: android, wifi

I was wondering how apps like the google home app and the oculus go app retrieve my saved wifi ssid and password. They do this to allow there respective devices to connect to my wifi network.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I don't know how the oculus go app works, but reading the instructions the app requests the user to enter the wifi password. Google Home is signed by Google and it is allowed to access hidden API which may also access the wifi password. Assume that the Google Home app runs like on a rooted device, where you are able to access the password. With public API it is not possible to get the wifi password.

There is one exception and I don't know if facebook uses that: If you once entered the password in an app which in turn creates the wifi connection for you, it may save that password somewhere to let you connect other devices as well with the same network.